# Unable to install packages, error by software management

Tags: software-installation, software-center, gdebi

I am unable to install `.deb` file because of this error from gdebi

```
Only one software management tool is allowed to run at the same time

Please close the other application e.g 'Update manage', 'aptitude' or 'synaptic' first.
```

Comment: Try closing **all** other programs, then try again.

Comment: If that doesn't work, try restarting your computer.

Comment: I think you're using Linux Mint Cinnamon. btw, is your problem solved?

Answer (score 4):

There is a conflict between gdebi and some other package management program - Software Center for GNOME, Ubuntu Software Center, Software Updater, Synaptic, apt, aptitude, etc. There can be only one software management program installing/updating software at the same time. To remove the conflict, close the terminal and close all other software management tools, except for the single one that you are currently trying to use.