# Can't install deb file, Gdebi claims there is other software management tools running

Tags: package-management, software-installation, gdebi

I tried to install a deb package with Gdebi, Ubuntu software was running at the time, but it didn't show any warning and started installing, then it got stuck without any progress and eventually I had to shut down the PC, so I killed the process mid installation.

After that, when I try to install the package again the following comes out:

> Only one software management tool is allowed to run at the same time. Please close the other application (e.g. Update Manager, aptitude, or synaptic) first.

This persists even after a reboot, so I don't know what management software could possibly be going. I tried using Ubuntu software to install a program and it was able, so it must be a problem with Gdebi.

Using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Anybody knows what might be happening?

Thanks for your time.

Edit:
Output of suod apt-get update:

````
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal InRelease   
Get:3 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB] 
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]  
Get:5 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Get:6 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [283 kB]
Get:7 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [361 kB]
Get:8 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]
Get:9 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [10,4 kB]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [29,0 kB]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [62,5 kB]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2.464 B]
Fetched 1.078 kB in 1s (860 kB/s)              
Reading package lists... Done
```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install packages, error by software management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/820712/unable-to-install-packages-error-by-software-management)

Comment: No, I already read that thread, I have closed all the apps I could identify, as I stated, the problem persists even after a reboot.

Comment: Please open terminal and execute `sudo apt-get update` . Then share output.

Comment: @N0rbert I edited the question with the output.

Comment: Output is correct. Let's install something with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall nano` .

Comment: Output was :`E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.`
Guess I sould do as it says?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to resume package installation procedure by executing the following commands:

```
sudo rm -v /var/lib/dpkg/lock* /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help.